# PDP page customise if open from qr code

Tags: magento2, products, pdp

I want to know about the PDP page.
How can I difference between if the product is open from qr code or list page itself.
I want to customise the PDP page if the product is open from the QR code scan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To differentiate between whether a product is opened from a QR code scan or from the list page, you can pass a unique parameter in the URL when the QR code is scanned.

Something like this,

```
https://www.example.com/products/product-name?source=qr_code
```